# Can a background service wake more frequently when the device is AC powered?

Tags: android

I appreciate Doze's 15 minute restriction on background services, but does the limitation apply when the device is AC powered? Is there a minimum interval between wakes when the device is AC powered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doze doesn't depend on if its AC powered.  What you can do (if its your own device) is turn on the setting that keeps the display on when connected to power.  That would prevent Doze as well.

Comment: Right. I've read that Doze can be switched off (for a specific app) by some whitelisting through the Battery setting. But if I go to that on my phone, quite a few apps are automatically 'not optimised'. Does that mean they ignore Doze by default? Do they just use the permission `<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>`?

Comment: Yes, it can.  However you can't turn off the setting yourself-  all the permission allows you to do is ask the user to turn on the setting and bring them to the page.  A preinstalled app can have that setting turned on automatically by the OEM, but a normal app can't turn it on itself.